# how to position row in the middle react semantic ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

how would i position the row to be in the middle using react semantic ui grid row? Wondering if there is another way besides increasing the padding-top until it reaches the middle

```
<Container>
        <Grid columns={4} divided>
          <Grid.Row>TITLE</Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={4} color="violet" textAlign="center">
              <h3>Content</h3>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column textAlign="center" width={4} color="violet">
              <h3>Content</h3>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column textAlign="center" width={4} color="violet">
              <h3>Content</h3>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column textAlign="center" width={4} color="violet">
              <h3>Content</h3>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [verticalAlign prop](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid/) and provide a value `middle` to the `Grid.Row` to solve your issue. Also make sure to provide a height to the grid.

As per documentation:

- A grid can specify its vertical alignment to have all its columns vertically centered.
- A row can specify its vertical alignment to have all its columns vertically centered.

[Working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-gid-centered-ji110?file=/example.js)

```js
<Container style={{ height: "100vh", background: "lightblue" }}>
    <Grid
      style={{ height: "400px", background: "gray" }}
      columns={4}
      divided
      padded={false}
    >
      <Grid.Row verticalAlign="middle">
        <Grid.Column width={4} color="violet" textAlign="center">
          <h3>Content</h3>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column textAlign="center" width={4} color="violet">
          <h3>Content</h3>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column textAlign="center" width={4} color="violet">
          <h3>Content</h3>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column textAlign="center" width={4} color="violet">
          <h3>Content</h3>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  </Container>
```

Comment: is there a way to add spacing between the columns

Comment: The columns already have padding but we are providing the background color which makes it look no space .... So, to the content of the column just style it with different color and provide padding...i have updated the code in the sandbox....Use the same codesandbox demo link (just refresh page)